# RECAPTCHA Always showing on a mobile device

Tags: recaptcha

We are implementing reCAPTCHA, and having issues where it ALWAYS shows up on the users mobile device, regardless of the rules we have established.
Desktop works just fine, but we can't figure out what we are doing wrong that it always displays on mobile, and makes the customer choose.

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to browser version of mobile device is outdated or cookies is looked malicious.